# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', I am not getting sum of all the numbers

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

I was trying to sum up all the numbers which I took as the input from the user and split it.
But its showing an error..

Code:

```
n = 1
input_num = int(input('How many numbers will you eneter?: '))
for i in range(input_num):
   numbers = int(input('Enter number '+ str(n) + ': '))
   n = n + 1

split_numbers = str(numbers).split()

print(sum(split_numbers))

if n > input_num:
    break
```

Output:

```
print(sum(split_numbers))
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I was expecting that it should sum up all the numbers which I took from the user and split it, but its showing an error

Comment: `sum(map(int, split_numbers))`

Comment: `split_numbers` type is `str` you need to convert into `int` datatype

Comment: @Unmitigated I tried to do that, its not giving error but its not showing the sum

Comment: `print(sum(map(int, split_numbers)))`** you used print statement? @EklavyaJain

Comment: Assume you input only three numbers and write down in paper what you expect your code to do, for every single step of the `for` loop. What is `numbers` when the loop is over? Which type of data should it be, which value(s) should it have?

Comment: When you do `split_numbers = str(<something>)`, what should happen? Which type of data do you expect `split_numbers` to be? If you where the computer, what would you do when you are asked to do `sum(split_numbers)`?

Comment: Because of its indentation `if n > input_num` is going to be executed after everything else. So `n` _must be_ `input_num` + 1, and therefore greater than `n`... But anyway, what are you trying to break with `break`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you prompt the user for one single number, as many times as the amount of numbers that should be inputted, what are you splitting?

Answer (score 0):

```
input_num = int(input('How many numbers will you enter?: '))
total = 0
for i in range(input_num):
    number = int(input('Enter number {}: '.format(i+1)))
    total += number

print('The sum of the numbers is: {}'.format(total))
```

Maybe this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

hi for sum inputs you should append inputs in the list and sum it you can't sum string values

```
n = 1
l = []
input_num = int(input('How many numbers will you eneter?: '))
for i in range(input_num):
    numbers = int(input('Enter number '+ str(n) + ': '))
    l.append(numbers)
    n = n + 1
print(sum(l))'
```

Comment: _you should append inputs in the list and sum it_... Why? It would be easier to sum the numbers on the go.